# Do I need to protect my api keys in React Native and if so how do I do this?

Tags: api, react-native

Do I need to hide my api keys in React Native in like a .env file or are they okay being left in a .js file.

Comment: What would be the difference between a .env and a .js file in this case (assuming both get packaged into your app)?

Comment: tldr; doesn;t matter, apps built for release cannot be reverse engineered

Answer (score 0):

This is all depend upon you like if you want to manage your constants and API keys separately then **.env** file would be better option here where you can manage your API keys separately via **.env** file and you can manage your all the app constants there if **.js** file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use .env file to save your API keys and your payment gateways keys.
2. enable proguard in gradle files to encrypt the keys.